# Is Vulgate John 8:25 a grammatically valid translation of the Greek?

Tags: greek, john, grammar, latin-vulgate

For **John 8:25**, the Vulgate has:

> Dicébant ergo ei: Tu quis es? Dixit eis Jesus: Princípium, qui et
>   loquor vobis.
>
> *They said therefore to him: Who art thou? Jesus said to them: The
>   beginning, who also speak unto you.*

**My question is twofold:**

1) Is the Vulgate translation valid grammatically?

2) Should the Greek be ὅτι or *ho ti* (he who)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Greek reads καὶ εἶπεν αὐτοῖς ὁ Ἰησοῦς· τὴν ἀρχὴν ὅ τι καὶ λαλῶ ὑμῖν, which has ἀρχή ("beginning") in the accusative case.  The Latin *principium* is a 2nd declension neuter noun that could be either accusative or nominative.

In fact, neither conveys what appears in most English translations (*... from the beginning*).  The phrase "from the beginning" would have been indicated by ἀπʼ ἀρχῆς (e.g. Matt 24:21) or ἐξ ἀρχῆς (e.g. John 6:64), which take ἀρχή in the genitive and not the accusative case and require a preposition.

So in answer to your question, I would say that yes, the Vulgate is accurately translating the Greek phrase (Latin accusative, it seems, for Greek accusative).  But the Greek itself seems somewhat ambiguous.

Metzger's *Textual Commentary on the New Testament* offers the following additional insights:

> Since the older Greek manuscripts lack punctuation and are written without division between words, it is possible to interpret Τὴν ἀρχὴν … ὑμῖν in several ways:
>
> (1)      As a question, with ὅτι = why? (“Why do I speak to you at all?”).
>
> (2)      As an exclamation, with ὅ τι in the sense of the Hebrew ‮מָה‬ (“That I speak to you at all!”).
>
> (3)      As an affirmation, with ὅ τι and supplying ἐγώ εἰμι (“[I am] from the beginning what I am telling you” or “Primarily [I am] what I am telling you” or “[I am] what I have told you from the beginning”).
>
> Several Latin witnesses (and the Gothic), misunderstanding the Greek, translate Principium, qui et loquor vobis (“[I am] the Beginning, even I who speak to you”). The Ethiopic omits ὅτι (“[I am] the Beginning, and I told you so”). The Bodmer Papyrus II (66) reads, according to a marginal correction that may be by the original scribe, Εἶπεν αὐτοῖς ὁ Ἰησοῦς, Εἶπον ὑμῖν τὴν ἀρχὴν ὅ τι καὶ λαλῶ ὑμῖν (“Jesus said to them, I told you at the beginning what I am also telling you [now]”).

The Metzger commentary further notes:

> For full discussions of the difficulties of the passage, see R. W. Funk, *Harvard Theological Review*, LI (1958), pp. 95–100, and E. R. Smothers, S.J., *ibid.*, pp. 111–122, who independently prefer the reading of 66c.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I suspected strongly that *τὴν ἀρχὴν* was not what one would expect if 'from the beginning' was meant.

Comment: The accusative singular τὴν ἀρχήν is widely used in Classical and post-Classical Greek to mean “in the beginning, at first”.  
See Liddell/Scott: http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.8:10:92.LSJ
(meaning A c).